# Is it possible to add a Uv cube mapping to a CuboidMesh in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am developping a 3D cube with 6 different textures and I wanted to know if it's possible to use a cube Uv mapping for a CuboidMesh in QML.

If it's possible, how can I do it ?

I try it but I have the following result :

[image]

Here is my code for all the scene including the cube :

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.15



Entity {
    id: root
   
    Entity {
            id: cubeEntity


            Texture2D {
                id: cubeTexture

                TextureImage {
                    source: "qrc:/texture.png"
                }
            }

            CuboidMesh {
                id: cubeMesh
                xExtent: 1
                yExtent: 1
                zExtent: 1
            }

         Transform {
                id: cubeTransform
            }

            ObjectPicker {
                id: cubePicker
            }

            NormalDiffuseMapMaterial{
                id: cubeMaterial
                diffuse: cubeTexture
                normal: cubeTexture
                specular: "black"
                shininess: 50
            }

            components: [cubeMesh, cubeTransform, cubeMaterial, cubePicker]

    }

}
```

It works with the Mesh type but I want to use that mapping with a CuboidMesh.

My texture.png is the following image :

[image]

Comment: Can you provide [mcve] of your attempt to do that?

Comment: Yeah sure, i will edit my post

Comment: did you see [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html), it creates a dice and has an image like you. but use opengl

Comment: I want to create something like this  in qt3d , I finally create this obj in the blender and then add it to my project . this was the easiest way

Comment: Yes I see this example in Qt Parisa but I don't have to use OpenGl and I do the same thing at the beginning but my boss say me to use the nativ CuboidMesh

Comment: I will use my Blender model and apply the uv map texture, it's works better